# Select query returning false on sql server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, select

I am using SQL(MSSQL) Server database on Windows Server. My database connection is working perfect.
I am trying to get data using Select Query.
Here is my code,

**db_functions.php**

```
 public function login($username, $password)
 {

   $sqlString = "SELECT CompId , BUCode , Role from 
   PRIME_APPUSR WHERE UserName = ? AND PassWord = ?";

   $params = array($username, $password);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sqlString, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) {

        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);

    if ($rows === true) {

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) {

            $response["CompId"] = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);
            $response["BUCode"] = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 1);
            $response["Role"]   = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 2)

        }

        return $response;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**login.php**

```
 <?php

  require_once 'db_functions.php';
  $db = new db_functions();

  if (isset($_POST['USERNAME']) && isset($_POST['PASSWORD'])) {

  $USERNAME = $_POST['USERNAME'];
  $PASSWORD = $_POST['PASSWORD'];

  $result1 = $db->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  if (!$result1) {

    $arr["response"] = "Error.";

  } else {

    $arr["response"] = $result1;

  }

  echo json_encode($arr);

  } else {

    $arr["response"] = "Invalid Parameters";
    echo json_encode($arr);

  }

?>
```

my question is , i am getting a false in return from this function.
can anyone guide to solve this.?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `"SELECT CompId , BUCode  Role` you are missing a comma before `Role`

Comment: And this is ***ABSOLUTELY NOT THE WAY TO STORE/RETRIEVE PASSWORDS***

Comment: @Martin : hi Placed the misplaced comma , the actualy query was large so written only 3 columns here. corrected in the code.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri : false value returned

Comment: `@RigertaDemiri : false value returned` returned from where exactly?

Comment: @Martin : login.php is from where i am executing the function.

Comment: @Martin  : I know its not the way but this is very first query i am starting to work with PHP. Please guide me to solve this, i wont be able to move ahead and learn until i get to solve this.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri : code updated

Comment: @javabee have you checked your PHP error logs? Have you output you values so you know that a) the values are in the database and b) the query values are correct?

Comment: this approach is not secure, try to use http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php and maybe this https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0

Comment: @Martin question is about **MSSQL**

Comment: @Martin : Found the issue. there are 300 rows in my table, and none of them matching the values i am actually cross checking with.

Answer (score 0):

$sqlString = "SELECT CompId , BUCode,  Role from 
   PRIME_APPUSR WHERE UserName = ? AND PassWord = ?";

I think you need ' , ' between BUCode and Role

Comment: hi Placed the misplaced comma , the actualy query was large so written only 3 columns here. corrected in the code.

Comment: @javabee please show your full SQL so we can see what may cause it to fail

Comment: @Martin : Another file added. 
my database connections are working hence added only this file